# Is AngularJS really MVC?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

I'm looking through examples on [the AngularJS home page](http://angularjs.org/) — specifically “Add Some Control”. I don’t quite understand how it maps to MVC pattern.

It’s more or less clear that the template (index.html) can be thought of as the view, objects constructed by TodoCtrl from todo.js as the controller, but where is a model? Attributes like `ng-model` map to some internal pieces of the framework and don’t directly expose an object which we could call a model.

Is it correct to call AngularJS an MVC framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes map into the scope variable as defined in the controller. For example, if you have some JS objects which represent your business logic, you can put those in the scope variable, and then the attributes can be mapped into the model itself instead of some arbitrary values in the scope variable.

Comment: So examples on home page aren't really MVC ones? Do I need to go deeper to see MVC in AngularJS?

Comment: @PaulLysak there are further examples in the docs. You don't really need a separate "model" in order for it to be MVC, and the definition of MVC is a bit loose anyway. In the example you're referring to, the model is essentially what is put in the `$scope` variable. It's just a simple model and only used in the single controller.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified a lot!

Answer (score 23):

The core idea behind MVC is that you have clear separation in your code between
managing its data (model), the application logic (controller), and presenting the data
to the user (view).
The view gets data from the model to display to the user. When a user interacts with the
application by clicking or typing, the controller responds by changing data in the model.
Finally, the model notifies the view that a change has occurred so that it can update what
it displays.
***In Angular applications***, the **view** is the Document Object Model (DOM), the **controllers**
are JavaScript classes, and the **model** data is stored in object properties.

Answer (score 8):

I havent read up on Angular. However, keep in mind that "true" MVC means that the Model contains business Logic, the Controller takes care of communicating user input to the Model, and the View gets its own data from the Model. Many so called MVC frameworks are actually not implementing MVC the right way: They are overloading the Controller With to much responsibility, as in making the Controller responsible also to update the View. That is not what the Controller was intended to do, and in such cases you get what is called a "fat Controller". There is a misconseption among many webdevelopers that the View is simply a "template". This is both true and false; It is a template but it get its own data directly from the Model - not via the Controller.

But as I started out saying: I havent yet read up on Angular, but you might have so yourself and you should be able to find out if Angular is truly a MVC framework by looking at what the different Components in the Framework does.

Answer (score 3):

If anything that can store data in a object is considered a model than every front end framework (view) could be considered to have a model. They can all store data in objects and present them in the view. I think calling angular a mvc is really a marketing ploy, trying to make angular seem like it is more than it is.

See:
https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/tutorial-angularjs-mvc-implementation

In the controller, is where they give their example of angular's as a model. If it can't assist in the storage of persistent data it isn't much of a model.